# FCM Push Notifications: Encountering Bad Request Issue

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a total of 10,000 requests that I'm sending using FCM push notifications. Within these requests, I'm encountering instances where I receive a "502: Bad Gateway" error. Interestingly, when I place these requests in Postman, they return a "200 OK" success response. Despite attempting to resend the requests using a retry mechanism, I continue to face the same error. How can I go about resolving this issue?

I tried using retry mechanism .